# Creating A Backup DVD of Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10, backup, windows-10-upgrade

I purchased Windows 8.1 around 2 years back, I have the original DVD, and installed it on my laptop. Later, I upgraded it to Windows 10 around 8 months back. I want to completely remove everything from my laptop and install Linux OS on it. Before doing this, I want to make sure that I've somehow backed up my Windows 10 (OS only, not data) in some sort of DVD form. So that, in future when I want to install Windows again, I can have my Windows 10 back, instead of old Windows 8.1.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool from Microsoft [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and it will let you download an .iso image file of the Windows 10 installation media and optionally use it to create a bootable USB flash stick or DVD.

Comment: It will only backup OS and not any data. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. The images this tool lets you download and write to USB/DVD are clean OS-only images straight from Microsoft, with none of your user data added.

Comment: @OmarTariq At the risk of stating the obvious, but the procedure above will not backup _anything_ from your existing installation. It would simply provide you with a generic Windows 10 installation media. In particular, if your machine currently has any hardware/peripherals drivers that don't come with the generic reinstall media, then you'll have to look those up and reinstall them by yourself. Same applies to any 3rd party software that you may have currently installed.

Comment: While installing Windows 10 from the the media disc I've created using Windows 10 Media Creation Tool, it will require me to enter the product key. Do my Windows 8.1 key will work? Or it will not ask for the product key?

Comment: @OmarTariq Once Windows 10 has been activated, the information is stored by Microsoft. The product key is not required if Windows 10 is installed again.

Answer (score 1):

Search for `Create a recovery drive` to get this:

[image]

Comment: The requirement is to clean everything from the laptop and install Linux OS on it. This includes formatting all the drives. But I truly appreciate your answer as it has increased my knowledge.

Comment: @OmarTariq This writes the system image to a 8GB USB drive. It will include any drivers which might not be on the standard Windows image. You can then format your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Windows 10 ISO direct from Microsoft. Save the ISO file somewhere. Windows 10 when activated it for the first time, it saves all hardware information on their servers. Everytime you need to reinstall the windows you don't have to input the windows key, it's activate automatically when you get online. Make sure you download the Windows 10 X64, here's the link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10iso

Comment: `1.` Does this mean that my Windows 8.1 key, which can now legitimately be used for Windows 10, will be voided if I switch to an SSD? `2. ` I'm currently using Windows 10, upgraded from Windows 8.1, does this mean that I'm already registered and that I do not need Windows 8.1 key if I've to install Windows 10 from ISO in my laptop in the future?